# PayPal Express Checkout default Country

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm trying to default the billing country to the UK, but no matter what i try it always defaults to the US.

Any ideas?

Note, that we do not require the customer to enter a shipping address so this has been hidden as per the json but have tried setting this to see if it makes a difference with no joy.

I've tried the following:

```
                json_patch_request: [
                    {
                        op: 'replace',
                        path: '/payer/payer_info/billing_address',
                        value: {
                            country_code: 'GB',
                        }
                    }
                ],
                payer: {
                    payer_info: {
                        country_code: 'GB',
                        billing_address: {
                            country_code: 'GB',
                        },
                        shipping_address: {
                            country_code: 'GB',
                        }
                    }
                },
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: {
                                total: 10,
                                currency: 'GBP'
                            },
                            custom: 'x',
                        },
                    ],
                },
                experience: {
                    input_fields: {
                        no_shipping: 1
                    },
                    flow_config: {
                        landing_page_type: "billing",
                    },
                    presentation: {
                        locale_code: "GB",
                    },
                }
```

[image: problem screen shot]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set that in your seller profile:

1. Log in to your PayPal account
2. Click Money at the top of the page
3. Click Manage Currency
4. Choose the currency to make Primary
5. Click Make Primary

See https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments-Archive/How-to-change-Paypal-default-currency-to-USD/td-p/616528

Comment: This did not appear to make any difference.